# Should i keep css of home page and landing pages in seperate css?

Tags: css, xhtml

Should i keep CSS of home page and landing pages in separate CSS file of big sites. ?

If i make site with a 7-8 different templates where 1 templates of home pages 1 is for inner content pages and other template for different type of landing pages.

and different style needed for same HTML elements in website ,

**For example** :

for inner pages H2 has different style but for landing pages H2 is different in color, font -size, line height, top bottom margin

How i should manage all this ? any tips to make good,easily manageable, scan-able CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about using different `<body id="home_page">`  `<body id="download_page">` and so on!?

or something like `wrapper` or `content` as usual instead of using body!

so you have:

```
body { padding:0; margin: 0; text-align:center; } /*applied to all*/    
h2 { font: normal normal 14px sans-serif } /*applied to all*/    
#home_page h2 { color: #333 }   /* home page only */ 
#download_page h2 { color: #666 } /* download page only */
```

just an example but you got the idea!

**UPDATE**

if you are using CMS, i don't know if is a common cms or one created by you, and also i don't know if you are free to edit it as you want in a custom way, or need to be a plug and play for client!

Assuming you are rendering all the pages content with php, then you can

> 1 - check for what page the user is
>   viewing and switch style! not very
>   elegant although!
>
> 2 - your cms may have OR if of your
>   creation should have some option for
>   theme creation like:

```
define( DEFAULT_STYLE , true ); //or false this would make my very fisrt responce real!
```

> 3 - render the CSS from backend
>   `header("Content-type: text/css");`
>   based on what is the user request!

Comment: the problem of this method is we work on CMS which already adds ID to `<body id="download_page">` but the problem can arise for other pages bcoz  this function is dynamic , for example if client will change "download page" to "download section" then body will be changed to `<body id="download_section">` and css will not work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of the CSS is reusable and how much is specific.

Comment: typography of home and landing pages is different and for other pages it's same. header and footer, width of container ae same across the site.

Comment: And the typography consists of what? 5% of the CSS? 97% of the CSS?

Comment: typography of site is consistent in 95% cases other than 5% which is on home and landing pages. The problem is in inner pages I use h1 h2 as needed in content but on home and landing pages which has boxes for different purposes in that boxes I also use h2 , h3 etc for content boxe's heading where i need different color, font -size, line height, top bottom margin of heading and other typographic elements

Comment: and css of site will be handled by other people after finished my work if any changes comes in future in design from client side.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - you should never just overwrite h2 in such cases, make it also class dependent, something like => h2.homepage / h2.subpage

Comment: @ntziolis - will class properties override on HTML selector's properties?